# Python print object volumes with the 3D-Print Toolbox

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Using the [3D-Print Toolbox add-on](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html) you can obtain object volumes. I have a lot of objects in my scene that I would like to print the volume value from and I was hoping I could do this through python. When I manually click on the Analyse -> Statistics -> "volume button" nothing shows up in the info panel where usually a new entry shows up after an action in the blender UI.

I would highly appreciate any ideas or feedback!

Alex

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the addon, all that operator is is a wrapper for the `bmesh.calc_volume()` function:

```
# from the addon
bm = mesh_helpers.bmesh_copy_from_object(obj, apply_modifiers=True)
volume = bm.calc_volume()
bm.free()
```

So you could probably just write something like:

```
import bpy
import bmesh


objs = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in objs:
    mesh = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)
    vol = bm.calc_volume()
    bm.free()
    print(vol)
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses internal calc_volume function from bmesh. You can replicate it like this:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in objs:
    me = obj.data
    if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
    else:
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(me)
        
    volume = bm.calc_volume()

    print(volume)
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigating into the add-on's folder you can find the function under `operators.py` > `MESH_OT_print3d_info_volume`

[image]

```
from object_print3d_utils import mesh_helpers
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
unit = scene.unit_settings
scale = 1.0 if unit.system == 'NONE' else unit.scale_length
obj = context.active_object

bm = mesh_helpers.bmesh_copy_from_object(obj, apply_modifiers=True)
volume = bm.calc_volume()
bm.free()

print("volume: ", volume)
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this from simplifying the existing code:

```
from object_print3d_utils import operators, mesh_helpers
print(str(mesh_helpers.bmesh_copy_from_object(bpy.context.active_object, apply_modifiers=True).calc_volume()/(operators.get_unit(bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.system, bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.length_unit)[0]/bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.scale_length)**(3))+" "+operators.get_unit(bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.system, bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.length_unit)[1]+str("³"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).